# How to view bootchart of an embedded device such as smartphone?

Tags: view, embedded, device

I have a laptop installed windows 7 x64 and a virtual machine with Ubuntu 12.04. I installed Bootchart on my virtual machine. I can view bootchart diagram of my virtual machine after log it on.

But I wonder... Is there any way to view bootchart diagram of an embedded device such as my android smartphone if i connect it to my laptop?

Can you help me to solve this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably off-topic for SO since it is not a programming question (on the face of it).  Try: http://elinux.org/Using_Bootchart_on_Android

Comment: Sry, i'm just a newbie in linux. I would like to know how to create a boot time log like bootchart when I connect a smartphone to my laptop and boot it on. Have anyone could help me to do this? I'm sry if my question is not related to programing, I just want to improve my knowledge. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a developer with the Android source code, you can use the following method and the bottom link to enable the bootchart on you smartphone.

brief instruction is like:

1. install the bootchart tool on your host machine
2. build 'init' with bootchart support
3. install 'init' into your system image
4. trigger bootchart functionality on system boot
5. retrieve the collected data from the system
6. generate the graphic from the data
7. view the resulting graphic
8. interpret the results

and more details please refer to :
http://elinux.org/Using_Bootchart_on_Android

Comment: Thank for your help. I've successfully generated bootchart on my device. My device is using systemd as init program. Systemd already has bootchart, and I obtained it via bootctl command :)

Answer (score 1):

dmesg command will be the one of the most helpful tool in providing log messages right from beginning of booting as far as any operating system based on linux. It prints the message buffer of kernel and it should also enable you to decode the boot sequence. You can also redirect the kernel messages using the 'console' command via the interface(UART / USB) that is available on the device.

Another interesting tool that could work in tandem with dmesg is netconsole if the device does not provision for other interface based logging or issues in disk logging. It sends all kernel log messages without any dependency on userspace, to another computer over the network (UDP) . However note that netconsole initializes only after NIC card initialization and hence capture of early kernel logs before this point will not be there but captures the rest of the boot process.